# Mapping Node not working?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

So I have been working on a sword and hit a roadblock once I started texturing it. I applied the texture and linked it to a Mapping Node but the Scale, Rotation and Location sliders do NOTHING. The only thing that actually changes the texture is scaling the UV beyond the UV grid but I discovered that this causes horrific problems when texture painting. I doesn't work in any mode.

Here is an image:

[image: Here is the image showcasing the problem]

And here is the .blend file if you want to inspect it closer. If you want, you can also check for other problems.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DVJO3BG2rUkSLw8ObOJpYmLimxi_5t5b